# How to .Include() multiple tables properly using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I have some issues trying to get data from my SQL database.

Having 3 model classes, `Set`, `SetContent` and `Item`:

```
public class Set
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string? Series { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SetContent> Content { get; set; }
}

public class SetContent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SetId { get; set; }
    public string? SetCode { get; set; }
    public string? SetRarity { get; set; }
    public string? SetRarityCode { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string ImageBig { get; set; }
    public string ImageSmall { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SetContent> Sets { get; set; } = new List<SetContent>();
}
```

I have 3 pages:

- one to display all `Sets`
- one to display `Content` of a specific `Set`
- one to display the specific `Item` details

The issue that I have is with the third one.

For the `Item` view page I would like to have a segment showing in what `Set` you can find it - so a combination of `Set` and `SetContent`.

I've tried using:

```
var card = _mapper.Map<ItemReadOnlyDto>(await _context.Items
            .Include(_c => _c.Sets)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == id));
```

but that didn't work out.

I'm able to get the data from `SetContent` using:

```
var item = await _context.Items.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync<Item>();
_context.Entry(item).Collection(s => s.Sets).Load();
```

but it has some obsolete data and reference loop nulls.

So the question here is how to, by querying the `Item`, get the data from `SetContent` and afterwards using `setId` from `SetContent` get the data from `Set`.

Something like this:

```
{
   "id": 0,
   "name": "string",
   "type": "string",
   "desc": "string",
   "imageBig": "string",
   "imageSmall": "string",
   "sets": [
   {
     "id": 0,
     "setId": 0,
     "setCode": "string",
     "setRarity": "string",
     "setRarityCode": "string",

     "SetName": "string",
     "ReleaseDate": "DateTime"
   }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add a navigation property from `SetContent` to `Set`:

```
// Removed other properties for brevity
public class SetContent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SetId { get; set; }
    public virtual Set Set { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the [`ThenInclude`](https://entityframeworkcore.com/querying-data-include-theninclude#theninclude) method:

```
var card = _mapper.Map<ItemReadOnlyDto>(await _context.Items
            .Include(_c => _c.Sets)
                .ThenInclude(sc => sc.Set)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == id));
```

And of course add some mapping for `item.Sets[n].Set`.